# Using a custom namespace instead of a default

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working in C# Visual Studio 2022. I have a referenced dll that has some directives I want to use. One of them is called System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. But in my class if I say using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations it is trying to use the namespace that is a member of System.ComponentModel.Annotations instead of my dll reference. How do I make this work?

Comment: Namespaces should be unique.  You should rename the namespace in your dll.

Comment: This is a third party dll, I cannot rename it.

Comment: How do you know, that the dll uses `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace?

Comment: I can look in Object Browser and see it under the dll

Comment: I'm not quite following.  A `using` is just programmer candy.  If I have a type like `My.Namespace.MyClass`, I can put a `using My.Namespace;` statement in at the top and reference the type as `MyClass` in my code.  Or, I can skip the `using` and just reference the type as `My.Namespace.MyClass`.  Or, if I have namespace/type collisions, I can say `using Mine=My.Namespace;` and reference the type as `Mine.MyClass`

Comment: So if I put using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations it is pulling in the namespace that is a Member of System.ComponentModel.Annotations. Instead I want System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to pull the namespace from the Member example Custom.dll that I have in my Dependencies -> Assemblies for my project

Comment: You can use [extern alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) in this situation.

Comment: I am trying extern alias and I don't know if that is what I need. So here is what I am dealing with. I have a dll that is lets say called Custom.dll. When I add that dll as a reference in my project, I can go to Object Browser in VS and see within Custom.dll there is Custom.Web, Custom.Portable, and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. So when I am in a class file in that project I can type in using Custom.Web just fine. But if I put using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations it is not referring to the namespace under my Custom.dll.

Comment: Are also the _classes_ within these namespaces colliding? Otherwise, you should be just fine. Several dlls containing the same namespace are not a problem, as long as the class names are different.

Comment: If you are done with your problem. You are more than welcome to answer your own questions.@Nathan

Comment: The third party was able to provide it as a local nuget package and that seems to work. Then when using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations it is now taking it from the correct source. I do not understand why having it as a nuget package all of the sudden fixes the problem but oh well.